# Convert list variables in a dataset into factor

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset with several variables that are lists (var_1 and var_2). My goal is to convert these variables to factor variables.

The dataset looks like this:

```
var_1    |   var_2
Value_1  |   Value_A
Value_2  |   Value_C
Value_3  |   Value_A
Value_43 |   Value_Z
Value_3  |   Value_A
Value_24 |   Value_Y
```

Here is what I have with a typeof() function:

```
typeof(mydataset$var_1)
[1] "list"

typeof(mydataset$var_2)
[1] "list"
```

Here is what I get with a str() function

```
str(mydataset)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  83 obs. of  6 variables:
$ var_1 :List of 83
..$ : chr "Value_1"
..$ : chr "Value_2"
..$ : chr "Value_3"
..$ : chr "Value_43"
..$ : chr "Value_3"
..$ : chr "Value_24"
 etc...
$ var_2 :List of 83
..$ : chr "Value_A"
..$ : chr "Value_C"
..$ : chr "Value_A"
..$ : chr "Value_Z"
..$ : chr "Value_A"
..$ : chr "Value_Y"
 etc...
```

How can I turn these variable into factor variable?

Comment: In base R, `dat[sapply(dat, is.list)] <- lapply(dat[sapply(dat, is.list)], function(x) factor(unlist(x)))` should be pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

Use `unlist`:

```
DT <- data.table(x = list("a", "b"), y = list("c", "d"))
DT[, names(DT) := lapply(.SD, function(l) factor(unlist(l)))]
str(DT)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ x: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2
#  $ y: Factor w/ 2 levels "c","d": 1 2
#- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: It doesn't work on my dataset.

It turned all values in figures....
     > head(fact_dataset)
        var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4 var_5 var_6
       1:     1     2     6     4     2     14
       2:     1     2     6     4     2     14
       3:     2     4     1     5     2      6
       4:     2     1     5     5     2     10
       5:     2     1     5     5     2      1
       6:     2     3     1     4     4      8

And the str() now looks like this:


> str(yoo)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 83 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ var_1 :List of 83
  ..$ : int 1
  ..$ : int 1

Comment: It's not my problem if you don't provide a minimal reproducible example. I recreated what you show in your question. Obviously, there is something you don't show.

Answer (score 0):

We use `mutate_all` for applying the function to each column, and within that use `map` as the columns itself are `list` of elements.  It is not clear whether the structure should be kept as such or not.  If it is, then use `map`, with `as.factor`

```
library(tidyverse)
mydataset %>%
          mutate_all(funs(map(., as.factor)))
```

If we need to keep it as normal columns, `unlist` and convert to `factor`

```
mydataset %>% 
         mutate_all(funs(factor(unlist(.))))
```

---

Also, from the `str`, it is a `data.table`, so using `data.table` methods

```
out <- mydataset[, lapply(.SD, function(x) lapply(x, factor))]
str(out)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ var_1:List of 2
#  ..$ : Factor w/ 1 level "Value_1": 1
#  ..$ : Factor w/ 1 level "Value_2": 1
# $ var_2:List of 2
#  ..$ : Factor w/ 1 level "Value_A": 1
#  ..$ : Factor w/ 1 level "Value_B": 1
```

#### data

```
mydataset <- data.table(var_1 = list("Value_1", "Value_2"), 
       var_2 = list("Value_A", "Value_B"))
```

Comment: It doesn't work on my dataset. It turned all values in figures.... > head(fact_dataset) var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4 var_5 var_6 1: 1 2 6 4 2 14 2: 1 2 6 4 2 14 3: 2 4 1 5 2 6 4: 2 1 5 5 2 10 5: 2 1 5 5 2 1 6: 2 3 1 4 4 8 And the str() now looks like this: > str(yoo) Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 83 obs. of 6 variables: $ var_1 :List of 83 ..$ : int 1 ..$ : int 1

Comment: @Remi. I showed an example that works for me.  You didn't provide a dput output.  So, it is is not clear

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mydataset[[1]] <- lapply(mydataset[[1]], as.factor)
```

Comment: thanks, there is an error message : Error in order(y) : type 'list' not available in 'orderVector1'

Comment: i didn't realize it was a data.table, i thought it was a list.  Try this: mydataset <- lapply(mydataset[[1]], as.factor)

Comment: It's still not working :( This turn the whole dataset into a list

Comment: My bad, mydataset[[1]] <- lapply(mydataset[[1]], as.factor)